# Firestore security rules working inconsistently across local development and production

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a problem regarding my firestore security rules.

The rules look like this:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /subjects/{subjectId}/{collectionId=**} {
           allow read, write: if request.auth != null && subjectId in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.subjects;
    }

    match /users/{userId}/{collectionId=**} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
    }

    match /mail/{document=**} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

**Why is my database structured like this ?**

The subject collection is basically an organization or a user. My app should work with organizations and teams or single users. That's why I decided to create a collection `subjects` where are stored most of my app's data. Actual users have a foreign key to this collection. They may receive the foreign key:

- on registration - the subject with `isOrganization: false` flag is created and linked to user. That's basically user's personal storage and he can invite other users to collaborate.
- they may create subject with `isOrganization: true` flag organization and invite others
- they may be added to an organization through an invitation.

**Expected behavior of the rules:**

- allow all authenticated users to access subject document listed in the users.subjects field
- allow all authenticated users to access their user document and subcollections of that document
- allow all authenticated users to create documents in mail collections

**Actual behavior of the rules:**

- Rules for mail and users collections are working as expected
- Rules for subjects collection is working locally with emulator but not working when deployed

**What I found so far:**

- I wrote a simple unit test for my firestore rules to test interactions between users and collections. Here is a snippet from my unit test

```
describe("Firestore security rules", async () => {
    beforeEach(async () => {
        testEnv = await initializeTestEnvironment({
            projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID,
            firestore: {
                rules: fs.readFileSync("firestore.rules", "utf8"),
                host: '127.0.0.1',
                port: 4040
            },
        });
    });

    it('users_test_case ', async () => {
        const alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice");
        const docRefValid = doc(alice.firestore(), "users", "alice");
        const docRefInvalid = doc(alice.firestore(), "users", "john");

        const testPayload = {
            name: 'Alice',
            subjects: ['test_subject_id', 'test_subject_id_1']
        }

        await assertSucceeds(setDoc(docRefValid, testPayload));
        await assertFails(setDoc(docRefInvalid, testPayload));
    });

    it('subjects_test_case ', async () => {
        const alice = testEnv.authenticatedContext("alice");
        const subjectDocRefValid = doc(alice.firestore(), "subjects", "test_subject_id");
        const subjectDocRefInvalid = doc(alice.firestore(), "subjects", "test_subject_id_3");

        const testPayload = {
            isOrganization: true,
        }

        await assertSucceeds(setDoc(subjectDocRefValid, testPayload));
        await assertFails(setDoc(subjectDocRefInvalid, testPayload));
    });
});
```

**The unit test is testing whether:**

- a user can access their document and can't access a document of others
- a user can access their subject and can't access subjects of others.

**Unit test results:**

- All tests pass but weird behavior is recorded in Firebase emulator suite. I'm attaching screens from firestore request monitor:
  [image]

**Request details of crashed and successful `CREATE` requests to `/subjects/test_subject_id`**
[image]

**Findings and questions:**

- As you can see users/ request are working as expected
- Only difference between the crashed one and the successful one is `resource undefined` in the crashed detail
- Why are 2 create requests sent to subjects/ when using setDoc ?
- How can I find out what exception occured in the firestore rules that returned ERROR response ?

**Local development connected to emulator test:**

- I decided to connect Firestore and Auth modules to local emulator
- Results where similiar to test one but small differences.

[image]

**Request detail screenshots:**
[image]

**Findings:**

- The request details here are completely the same with detailed informations with no difference except time stamp. Why one crashes and the other not ?

**Debugging firestore rules**

- I tried to look into `firestore-debug.log` and log some variables. All seems fine but this exception occures every time I run my tests

```
Jul 11, 2023 2:24:49 PM com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.util.WrappedStreamObserver onError
WARNING: Operation failed: 
false for 'create' @ L9, false for 'update' @ L9
com.google.cloud.datastore.core.exception.DatastoreException: 
false for 'create' @ L9, false for 'update' @ L9
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.core.exception.DatastoreException$Builder.build(DatastoreException.java:120)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.verboseError(EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.java:321)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.withVerboseErrors(EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.java:298)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.rules.EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.checkCommit(EmulatorRulesAuthorizer.java:130)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1.commitHelper(CloudFirestoreV1.java:1042)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1.internalCommit(CloudFirestoreV1.java:952)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1.internalCommit(CloudFirestoreV1.java:939)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1.write(CloudFirestoreV1.java:927)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.handleRequest(CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.java:210)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.write(CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.onNext(CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.java:93)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.emulator.impl.CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.onNext(CloudFirestoreV1WriteStream.java:26)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler$StreamingServerCallListener.onMessage(ServerCalls.java:262)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:33)
    at io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onMessage(Contexts.java:76)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onMessage(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:33)
    at io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onMessage(Contexts.java:76)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.messagesAvailableInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:324)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.messagesAvailable(ServerCallImpl.java:309)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:833)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
```

**Local development vs production**

- locally the app works fine without an error. Everything is listed/created as it should except some errors in firestore rules but it seems to have no effect on my frontend and it works as expected.
- production crashes with `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`
- **Firebase rules are exactly the same on production as are used locally**

Comment: It's interesting that this rule matches a create without a collectionId: `match /subjects/{subjectId}/{collectionId=**}`

What happens if you remove the collectionId portion?

If you think this might be a bug in the emulator, please file a bug here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/new/choose

Comment: @Chris The `collectionId=**` is basically a wildcard. The rule matches for requested document - `subjectId` or any subcollection of that document. I will probably create an issue as I have no clue what to do with this except of restructuring my database...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the information provided, it seems that the issue lies in the Firestore security rules for the "subjects" collection. To debug and resolve the issue, follow these steps:

1. Check Firestore logs: Go to the Firebase console, navigate to the Firestore section, and examine the logs for relevant error messages or warnings. [Firebase Firestore Logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/monitor-usage)
2. Review security rules for "subjects": Double-check the security rules for the "subjects" collection to ensure they allow the necessary read and write operations and have the correct data path. [Firebase Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)
3. Test rules using Firebase Rules Playground: Utilize the Rules Playground in the Firebase console to simulate and test your security rules with sample data. [Firebase Rules Playground](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/simulator)
4. Verify data in Firestore: Ensure the data in your Firestore database aligns with the security rules, checking the structure and expected values in the "subjects" collection. [Firebase Firestore Data Structure](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data)
5. Check Firebase project configuration: Confirm that your production Firebase project is properly configured and connected to your Firestore database, verifying project settings and API keys. [Firebase Project Settings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more#settings)
6. Consider Firebase/Firestore updates: Stay updated with the latest releases and documentation to ensure compatibility between your application, security rules, and any recent Firebase/Firestore updates. [Firebase Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases)